# error when I change the default site directory of apache2

Tags: 14.04, apache2, php, lamp

My system is Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit.

I installed apache&SQL&php and I want to change the default site directory from `/var/www/` to `/home/smile/Documents/public_sites/`. So I changed three steps:

step1: `sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite.conf`  and Change the DocumentRoot in `mysite.conf` to point to `/home/smile/Documents/public_sites/html`.

step 2: Change the Directory directive in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, replace `<Directory /var/www/>` to `<Directory /home/smile/Documents/public_sites/>`.

step 3: `sudo a2dissite 000-default && sudo a2ensite mysite` and `sudo service apache2 restart`

However, when I check the `http://localhost/`, these errors come out:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

This is the error.log:

```
[Fri Nov 21 11:01:56.740805 2014] [core:error] [pid 18485] (13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:48186] AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path '/home/smile/Documents/public_sites/') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
```

This is the part I changed: 
for mysite.conf:

```
#DocumentRoot /var/www/html
DocumentRoot /home/smile/Documents/public_sites/html
```

For the apache2.conf:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks 
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/smile/Documents/public_sites/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: you have made some modifications in mysite.conf, but based on what you said, you didn't update configuration to point to it , right?

Comment: @younes  hi, how can I update the configurations ?

Comment: It seems that step 2 goes wrong or that there are other `Directory` directive that need to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the directory explicitly in your `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Find the section that reads like this:

```
<Directory /usr/share/or_whatever >
Allow override none
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

where `granted` or `denied` is the explicit permission for this `non-standard` directory.
Without this directive everything outside of `/var/www/html` and `/usr/share` will be denied by default.

Everything else you've done seems to be right, also make sure you're both reloading and restarting apache2 after modifying these configs changes (sometimes they're stubborn)

```
sudo service apache2 reload
sudo service apache2 restart
```

A little brutish but I just make a habit of it to be sure.

Good luck!

Comment: I think this answer is close to the solution, although a restart should be sufficient.

Comment: this doesn't work. I modified my question and post the error.log.

Comment: Hi, looking at what you posted '/' is blocked but '/home/smile...' is allowed...i'm assuming that if the root folder is blocked any directories within it will be blocked by default as well.  Either allowing both or setting the allow override directive on root to allow the subdirectory.  With current settings, all subdirectories in '/' will be denied, including the one you've explicitly declared below it.  Refer to this link for guidance on the directive in question:  http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/doc/AllowOverride.htm  Hope this help.

Comment: Now error is changed and other answer (I don't remember user) that is removed now could help. try this link [(13) Permission Denied](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/13PermissionDenied)